# Ubuntu 18.04 for Production advice

Tags: ubuntu

Currently I have a laravel project that needs `7.2 php version` which is not offered in ubuntu 16 version. So I tried to upgrade and update the ubuntu version from 16 to 18 LTS just to get the `php version 7.2`.

The project is for long run and also I'm afraid to adjust my laravel project just to fit in with ubuntu 16.

Can I have your opinions or any situations that may cause for using ubuntu 18.04 LTS as production server?

Comment: 18.04 is the current LTS release. Why do you think it's not fit for production use?

Comment: I'm considering the stability of the server because some thread says that 16 is the stable version of ubuntu

Comment: I guess this thread is from before the release of 18.04. Because that is the current stable relase,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the 18.04 LTS. I have hosted a few Laravel projects on the Ubuntu 18.04 version and it works pretty much well.

Also, installing and maintaining PHP7 on Ubuntu 16.04 is also not a challenge and should not be a roadblock in your decision. See here: https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2
```

Both ubuntu versions (16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS) are very stable and are production-ready. Make up your mind and shoot.

Having said that, I would really recommend going for a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.